# Monodevelop Windows -> Linux Remote Debugging using Soft Debugger

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I'm writing an Addin for Monodevelop which can debug mono Applications
on remote Linux hosts based on the Meego Plugin. It seems like the
Meego Addin has been discontinued, so I tried to resurrect it as a
general Linux Remote Debugging Addin.

I got it up and running, and the Debugger connects successfully, Pause
and Continue works, but the Debugger ignores all breakpoints.

I think the problem might be with the Assembly path in the  MDB files
which are transfered to the Linux Host from my Windows PC, because
FindLocation in ResolveBreakPoint is null, and insideLoadedRange ==
false

Is there a way to change the Path info's in the MDB, so that I can
use them on windows and linux devices?

Comment: Did you ever write this plugin? Just what I need right now.

Comment: I am working on getting this working now. Anyone have any luck? Want to team up? PM

Answer (score 1):

The paths in a mdb file should match the location of the source files on the host machine (i.e. the IDE). For example, when a Windows machine is debugging a Mono for Android machine, the mdb files have Windows paths.

More likely the mdb files don't match the assemblies. When you run the app with `mono --debug appname.exe`, do stack traces have file and line info?